# Exception Unhandle System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net

This code is about viewing a published consultation schedule. Unfortunately I'm stuck with the if statement. The error occurs at line : If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then || I'm using a combobox to display the data from a database, which means there is a list of items in the combobox, and I will select any lecturer so it will display into the form. I have a database that contained the published schedule inside as shown at the pic. And all data stored in here(database) are actually unavailable(declared as red=unavailable, lime=available), except for the available does not stored into the database. So, what I'm doing now is to read and match the "Time", "Available" and "Lecturer" from the database, and change it to (red color) into the respective label(in lime colored).

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imy2q.png)

[The Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJejJ.png)

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class viewconsultationschedule
Dim time1 As String = "8.00am-10.00am"
Dim time2 As String = "10.00am-12.00pm"
Dim time3 As String = "12.00pm-2.00pm"
Dim time4 As String = "2.00pm-4.00pm"
Dim time5 As String = "4.00pm-6.00pm"
Dim day1 As String = "Monday"
Dim day2 As String = "Tuesday"
Dim day3 As String = "Wednesday"
Dim day4 As String = "Thursday"
Dim day5 As String = "Friday"

Dim conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=sdpdatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim sql As String
Dim sql2 As String
Private Sub ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ToolStrip1.ItemClicked

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    'If (ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 3) Then

    Dim time1 As String = "8.00am-10.00am"
        Dim time2 As String = "10.00am-12.00pm"
        Dim time3 As String = "12.00pm-2.00pm"
        Dim time4 As String = "2.00pm-4.00pm"
        Dim time5 As String = "4.00pm-6.00pm"
        Dim day1 As String = "Monday"
        Dim day2 As String = "Tuesday"
        Dim day3 As String = "Wednesday"
        Dim day4 As String = "Thursday"
        Dim day5 As String = "Friday"
        Dim conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=sdpdatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        sql = "Select * FROM consultationschedule WHERE Lecturer=@Lecturer" ' And [Time]=@Time AND weekDay=@weekDay "
        sql2 = "Select COUNT (*) FROM consultationschedule WHERE Lecturer=@lecturer"
        conn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(sql2, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lecturer", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Time]", time1)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weekDay", day1)

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lecturer", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
        'cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Time]", time2)
        'cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weekDay", day2)
        Dim count As Integer = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
        If (dr.HasRows) Then
        For i = 1 To count
            If (i = 1) Then
                dr.Read()

                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then

                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                        Label11.BackColor = Color.Red

                    Else
                        Label11.BackColor = Color.Lime
                    End If

                ElseIf (i = 2) Then
                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                            Label12.BackColor = Color.Red

                        Else
                            Label12.BackColor = Color.Lime


                        End If


                    ElseIf (i = 3) Then
                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                Label13.BackColor = Color.Red

                            Else
                                Label13.BackColor = Color.Lime


                            End If



                        ElseIf (i = 4) Then
                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                    Label14.BackColor = Color.Red

                                Else
                                    Label14.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                End If

                            ElseIf (i = 5) Then
                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                        Label15.BackColor = Color.Red

                                    Else
                                        Label15.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                    End If
                                ElseIf (i = 6) Then
                                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                            Label16.BackColor = Color.Red

                                        Else
                                            Label16.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                        End If
                                    ElseIf (i = 7) Then
                                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                Label17.BackColor = Color.Red

                                            Else
                                                Label17.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                            End If
                                        ElseIf (i = 8) Then
                                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                    Label18.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                Else
                                                    Label18.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                                End If
                                            ElseIf (i = 9) Then
                                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                        Label19.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                    Else
                                                        Label19.BackColor = Color.Lime


                                                    End If
                                                ElseIf (i = 10) Then
                                                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                            Label20.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                        Else
                                                            Label20.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                        End If
                                                    ElseIf (i = 11) Then
                                                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                Label21.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                            Else
                                                                Label21.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                            End If
                                                        ElseIf (i = 12) Then
                                                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                    Label22.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                Else
                                                                    Label22.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                End If
                                                            ElseIf (i = 13) Then
                                                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                        Label23.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                    Else
                                                                        Label23.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                    End If
                                                                ElseIf (i = 14) Then
                                                                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                            Label24.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                        Else
                                                                            Label24.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                        End If
                                                                    ElseIf (i = 15) Then
                                                                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                Label25.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                            Else
                                                                                Label25.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                            End If
                                                                        ElseIf (i = 16) Then
                                                                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                    Label26.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                Else
                                                                                    Label26.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                End If
                                                                            ElseIf (i = 17) Then
                                                                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                        Label27.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                    Else
                                                                                        Label27.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                    End If
                                                                                ElseIf (i = 18) Then
                                                                                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                            Label28.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                        Else
                                                                                            Label28.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                        End If
                                                                                    ElseIf (i = 19) Then
                                                                                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                Label29.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                            Else
                                                                                                Label29.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                                            End If

                                                                                        ElseIf (i = 20) Then
                                                                                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                    Label30.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                Else
                                                                                                    Label30.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                                End If
                                                                                            ElseIf (i = 21) Then
                                                                                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                        Label33.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                    Else
                                                                                                        Label33.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                                    End If
                                                                                                ElseIf (i = 22) Then
                                                                                                    If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                        If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                            Label34.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                        Else
                                                                                                            Label34.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                                        End If
                                                                                                    ElseIf (i = 23) Then
                                                                                                        If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                            If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                                Label35.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                            Else
                                                                                                                Label35.BackColor = Color.Lime
                                                                                                            End If
                                                                                                        ElseIf (i = 24) Then
                                                                                                            If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                                If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                                    Label36.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                                Else
                                                                                                                    Label36.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                                                                End If
                                                                                                            ElseIf (i = 25) Then
                                                                                                                If dr("Lecturer") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem Then
                                                                                                                    If dr("Available") = "1" Then
                                                                                                                        Label37.BackColor = Color.Red

                                                                                                                    Else
                                                                                                                        Label37.BackColor = Color.Lime

                                                                                                                    End If

                                                                                                                End If
                                                                                                            End If
                                                                                                        End If
                                                                                                    End If
                                                                                                End If
                                                                                            End If
                                                                                        End If
                                                                                    End If
                                                                                End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                        End If
                                                                    End If
                                                                End If
                                                            End If
                                                        End If
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You're selecting a single nameless value in your SQL query: `Select COUNT (*)` and then trying to read a value called "Lecturer": `dr("Lecturer")`.  That SQL query doesn't return a value called "Lecturer".  So that index (`"Lecturer"`) is out of range for the results of that query.

Comment: I see, would you mind to guide me a little because I'm not so sure about what to replaced in that : Select COUNT (*) statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting records from your first SQL command, but then *immediately discarding them* and replacing them with results from your second SQL command:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
```

That second command has no field called `"Lecturer"`, it's just a single `COUNT()` value.

It looks like what you want is to just remove this line entirely:

```
dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
```

Because you already execute `cmd2` above and store that single value in the `count` variable.

---

Also note that your loop isn't necessary:

```
For i = 1 To count
    If (i = 1) Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

This loop will, by design, only iterate once.  So you don't need a loop in the first place, just execute the code once as needed.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm able to view the data into my form, but right now it only shows the first row and column(1x1) to be red, other all are staying at the lime which is like nothing changed and I've just edited the codes. Kindly check it under my post.